# How can I remove the white margin between the div's

Tags: html, css, dom, margin

There is white margin between the div's I want to remove it so there is no margin at all

Here is the fiddle link : http://jsfiddle.net/sz3MD/5/

```
body  {
       margin: 0;
       padding: 0;
       background: orange;
       font: 10px/13px 'Lucida Sans',sans-serif;
    }

    .wrap {
       overflow: hidden;
       margin: 10px;
       background-color: #fff;
    }

    .box {
       float: left;
       position: relative;
       width: 14%;


    }

    .boxInner img {
       width: 100%;
    background-color: blue;

    }
```

Comment: I don't see any white margin at your code.

Comment: Try setting display: block to your images

Comment: @ManoloSalsas about 1 px in the right of the blue squares and about 2-3px in the bottom

Comment: @katranci thanks a lot thats what i'v nedded

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sz3MD/7/)**

**The Code Change:**

```
.boxInner img {
    background-color: #0000FF;
    border-collapse: inherit;
    display:block;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Hope this is what you are looking for.